# How do I translate an expression with an addition assignment operator to math notation?

Tags: notation

I feel really stupid asking this, but what is the correct way to write the second line of the following example in math notation?

**Example (JavaScript)**

```
var x = 2, y = 2;
x += 2 * y; // x = x + 2 * y
```

Would it be written as x := x + 2y?

Comment: Some authors will use $\leftarrow$ where you have $:=$ but it would be written in the same form nonetheless.

Comment: Just to be clear, what Parcly said applies to explaining algorithms in psuedocode. Outside of a context like that, math doesn't really do assignment-it's more like a functional programming language.